# How to remove ::marker from html css

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the below  element

[image]

and when I highlighted the dot icon ,  the html css shows as below while using F12 developer tools

[image]

[image]

How to remove the ::marker from the html.

I tried using the below code . But it is not getting fixed.

```
list-style:none;
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: is hiding the marker ok for you ?` li::marker {
  content: none;
}`, you cannot remove the `::marker` if you dont have access to the original code or file, where you might want to delete the code in the css file if you want to completely remove it.

Comment: @Zyfella A ::marker is a default psuedo element for list items in all browsers, so you won't remove it that way. @Mahi Your `list-style` is _not being applied_ - I do not know why as you should include the actual full code and not a limited screenshot. But you can see your reset is striked through, so its not being set. Settings `list-style` should indeed work.

Answer (score 2):

Update the display value of `li` to remove the `::marker`

```css
.no {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="no">list</li>
 <li>list</li>
 <li>list</li>
 <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The OP did mention `list-style` and was on the right track, I think it might be more beneficial to set `list-style: none;` than changing a `display` definition, which can have more side effects...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/* to remove bullets from an unordered list */
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* to remove bullets from an ordered list */
ol {
  list-style:none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I think `list-style: none;` should work.  But perhaps you're specifically trying to target the markers for some reason?  After some testing, I couldn't get rid of them with `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`.  However, setting content to an empty string seems to work in Chrome, at least:

```
li::marker {
    content: "";
}
```

In Safari, it looks like you can use `li::marker` to do things like change the color but setting the content to an empty string (or anything else) doesn't seem to work. Again, setting `list-style: none;` on the `ul` should get rid of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the property - list-style-type: none; on li.
Can refer to this [link](https://getcssscan.com/blog/how-to-remove-bullets-from-li-css)